# SIGKILL has no effect on a process running 100% CPU

Tags: ubuntu

I have a weird behaiviour on my pi4 running Ubuntu server 21.04. It's running correctly, but at after a while, a can see a process running 100% CPU from hours, and if I wait longer there are 2, 3 ... other processes running 100% CPU. They seem to be launched by a cron job (from the home automation Jeedom), but this is not my question.

The weird thing is I cannot kill them, even root user with kill -9 . The process is running R, but not responding.

```
#ps aux | grep 46149
www-data   46149 99.7  0.0   2040    80 ?        R    Oct04 633:33 sh -c (ps ax || ps w) | grep -ie "cron_id=7$" | grep -v "grep"
#sudo kill -9 46149
#ps aux | grep 46149
www-data   46149 99.7  0.0   2040    80 ?        R    Oct04 633:36 sh -c (ps ax || ps w) | grep -ie "cron_id=7$" | grep -v "grep"
```

In this example, the blocked process is 'ps', but this is not always the same. If a power off the pi, it restarts normally, but another blocked process will appear after a while. And I need to power off, because 'reboot' will not work.

Edit:
Using 'ps axjf' to see process tree

```
      1    7317    7317    1799 ?             -1 Sl       0    0:56 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id bf40089312cdb1d7707096fe6fc46520c7c1a17a70eac305473761976c1f4b7d -address /run/cont
   7317    7337    7337    7337 ?             -1 Ss       0    1:12  \_ /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
   7337    7391    7391    7337 ?             -1 S        0    0:02  |   \_ /usr/sbin/cron -f -L4
   7391  104917    7391    7337 ?             -1 S        0    0:00  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/CRON -f -L4
 104917  104919  104919  104919 ?             -1 Ss       0    0:00  |   |   |   \_ /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/core/php/watchdog.php >> /dev/null
 104919  104920  104919  104919 ?             -1 R        0 1521:41  |   |   |       \_ /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/core/php/watchdog.php >> /dev/null
   7391  395309    7391    7337 ?             -1 S        0    0:00  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/CRON -f -L4
 395309  395312  395312  395312 ?             -1 Ss      33    0:00  |   |       \_ /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/core/php/jeeCron.php >> /dev/null
 395312  395313  395312  395312 ?             -1 S       33    0:00  |   |           \_ /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/core/php/jeeCron.php
 395313  395341  395312  395312 ?             -1 S       33    0:00  |   |               \_ sh -c (ps ax || ps w) | grep -ie "cron_id=4$" | grep -v "grep"
 395341  395344  395312  395312 ?             -1 R       33  109:29  |   |                   \_ sh -c (ps ax || ps w) | grep -ie "cron_id=4$" | grep -v "grep"
   7337    7392    7392    7337 ?             -1 S        1    0:00  |   \_ /usr/sbin/atd -f
   7337    8613    8613    7337 ?             -1 Sl       0    6:16  |   \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -fc /etc/fail2ban/
   7337   11223   10184   10184 ?             -1 S       33    0:08  |   \_ php /var/www/html/core/class/../php/jeeCron.php cron_id=452778
   7337   18465   18465   18465 ?             -1 SNs      0    0:08  |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  168788   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:48  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  354445   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:27  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  356077   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:24  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  356301   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:25  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  362824   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:16  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  364208   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:14  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  366422   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:12  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  366848   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:12  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  367416   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:10  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  367576   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:11  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  18465  405605   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33    0:03  |   |   \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
   7337   18824   18465   18465 ?             -1 SN      33  174:59  |   \_ php /var/www/html/core/class/../php/jeeCron.php cron_id=301554
   7337   35774   18465   18465 ?             -1 SNl     33    0:31  |   \_ node /var/www/html/plugins/alexaapi/resources/alexaapi.js http://app_jeedom amazon.fr alexa.amazon.fr OtAkaDFZj3YlSEQg6T1VGk8Jq8
   7337   44738   44738   44738 ?             -1 SNs    106    0:00  |   \_ /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
   7337   44767   44766   44766 ?             -1 SN     107    1:13  |   \_ avahi-daemon: running [bf40089312cd.local]
  44767   44768   44766   44766 ?             -1 SN     107    0:00  |   |   \_ avahi-daemon: chroot helper
   7337   45616   18465   18465 ?             -1 SNl     33    4:20  |   \_ homebridge
  45616   45664   18465   18465 ?             -1 SNl     33    2:10  |   |   \_ homebridge-config-ui-x
   7337   46149   46102   46102 ?             -1 R       33 1931:04  |   \_ sh -c (ps ax || ps w) | grep -ie "cron_id=7$" | grep -v "grep"
   7337  407386   18465   18465 ?             -1 RN      33    0:00  |   \_ php /var/www/html/core/class/../php/jeeListener.php listener_id=2 event_id=379484 value='1310' datetime='2021-10-06 06:36:25'
   7317   22607   22607   22607 ?          22607 Ss+      0    0:00  \_ /bin/bash
```

Edit

I tried to kill parent: every level of the process tree has been killed, except the parent and the blocked process (2 processes this time with the same parent).  Now I have

```
root        5790  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Ss   Oct09   0:14  \_ [sh]
www-data  267740 99.4  0.0   2040    84 ?        RN   05:05 1032:49      \_ sh -c ps ax | grep "resources/alexaapi.js" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l HOME=/var/www LOGNAME=www-data PATH=/usr/bin:/bin SHELL=/bi
www-data  357120 99.5  0.0   2040    80 ?        RN   14:00 501:07      \_ sh -c (ps ax || ps w) | grep -ie "cron_id=469432$" | grep -v "grep" HOME=/var/www LOGNAME=www-data PATH=/usr/bin:/bin SHELL=/bin
```

And with 'ps-ef':

```
root        5790    5760  0 Oct09 ?        00:00:14 [sh]
www-data  267740    5790 99 Oct10 ?        1-01:58:16 sh -c ps ax | grep "resources/alexaapi.js" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l
www-data  357120    5790 99 Oct10 ?        17:06:33 sh -c (ps ax || ps w) | grep -ie "cron_id=469432$" | grep -v "grep"
```

Comment: Look at the process tree with `ps axjf` or similar. Probably it's child/parent are the issue for this.

Comment: Thanks NStorm, I edited the question to add the result of 'ps axjf'

Comment: find the parent process and get the id and kill the parent via "ps -ef "

Comment: Thanks Zareh, I killed parent, but the blocked process is still running. I edited the question with result.